# Windows 8.1 locking up

Tags: windows-8.1, freeze

Ok I have a weird issue. My laptop will lock up every so often. Done it twice this weekend and if I had to put a number on it I would say it happens ~once a week. sometimes more and sometimes less.

When it does it all sound stops. Mouse no longer responds. Numlock/capslock no longer changes state. The screen displays what ever it was on when it froze.

I have looked over the event viewer to see if I could find anything but nothing was there that I saw. There are no dump files because it never bluescreens. It just does a complete freeze.

Laptop is a Dell precision M6800 with an i7-4800MQ. [This page](http://www.ebay.com/itm/161257017184) has the full specs. I can get other info if y'all need it.

Comment: Update all the drivers and run your PC in safe mode.

Comment: Safe mode is not an option because this happens so rarely.

Comment: overheat would be first thing to check for - when was the last time it was properly stripped & cleaned? [not just the vents brushed a bit from the outside]